# A way to optimise multiple .each with ajax-json request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

I have a lots of chart (hightchart )to generate in the same page , and it take at least 5-6 seconds to load all  my chart..

Html Page:

```
    <div class="graph_score" title="2" >
    <div class="graph_score" title="3" >
    <div class="graph_score" title="4" >
    <div class="graph_score" title="5" >
....
```

My jquery:

```
    $(".graph_score").each(function() {
      id_graph = $(this).attr("title");

      $.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + '/school/teachers/generate_score/graph' + id_graph, function(data) {
            options = data;
            options.tooltip = {
            formatter: function() {
                var extrafield = this.series.options.extrafield;
                var extrafield2 = this.series.options.extrafield2;
                var extrafield3 = this.series.options.extrafield3;
                return '<b> Note: ' + this.y + ' % <br/>' + '<b>Nom de l\'examen:</b>' + extrafield[this.point.x - 1] + '</b><br/><b>Pondération</b>' + extrafield2[this.point.x - 1] + "<br /><b>Date</b>" + extrafield3[this.point.x - 1];
            }
            }
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    })
```

Can I do something to render this page faster ?

*I know the problem is my script call 8 time **http://' + document.domain + '/school/teachers/generate_score** so its 8 DOM request ..... But I dont know how to optimize that...

Thx

Comment: Try adding some timers to your script to see where the bottleneck lies - it's either in the retrieval of your data in the AJAX request or the display of the data. My guess would be that it's the AJAX that's taking the time. Have a look at ways of speeding up your server-side code.

Comment: Also, you could look at returning all the data for your graphs in 1 call, and then dissecting the JSON for each graph individually. Again it depends on how quick your server is and how many connections it accept whether this will be a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

If you think the network transmission is taking a long time, then you could create a new function on the server that takes a list of IDs and returns several results.

Comment: Also, you'll want to make sure your Web server is compressing the data (so there is less to transmit)